# API give result as per usertype

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Usertypes table

[image]

User Table
[image]

I want to create api which give data particular user_type_id.. when i click api/usertype/1 than show only player list of user

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question where you're having difficulty. Please can you provide more information about what part you're struggling with.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried?

Comment: like api api/usertype/1 than show all user of which 1 number usertype -@Rwd

Comment: when i click on admin show only admin and when i click user show user list - @Abiola

Comment: @Kinnu123 Have you define any relation in your model?

Comment: no -@AmitSenjaliya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API route should be:

```
Route::get('/api/usertype/{id}', 'HomeController@getUsertype');
```

Your API controller:

```
use DB;
/** You have pass user_type_id **/
public function getUsertype($id){

    $user = DB::table('users')                
            ->where('user_type_id', $id)
            ->select('users.*')
            ->get();

    dd($user);  
}
```

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class &#039;App\Http\Controllers\DB&#039; not found in file /home/ynvih0l26evc/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/UserTypeController.php on line 109 - @Amit Senjaliya

Comment: @Kinnu123 Add `use DB;` facade in controller.